# How can a website tell I am using a VPN to connect off-campus?

Tags: vpn

My university provides a VPN we can use to connect to on-campus resources (such as databases) while we are off-campus. Connecting to the VPN shows an IP address belonging to my university, which is enough for those databases to grant access.

However, the IPTV service we use recently started detecting when we are connected to the VPN instead of actually being on campus, and says something along the lines of, "You must be on campus to watch live TV."

How is the IPTV service able to distinguish between VPN users and actual on-campus users, and is there a way to bypass this check?

Comment: What kind of connection do you use on Campus ?
The same VPN, another VPN or a transparent access?
The IPTV certainly knows the VPN IPs so no surprise.
Have you tried to connect to the IPTV on Campus?
If the Network is well done there is no way to bypass this with simple tweaks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If the IPTV service is usually used with the campus network, there are several possibilities:

- the campus network detects VPN users and blocks the service or flags the user
- VPN users are routed through another public IP/subnet than other users

Bypassing such filters is explicitly off-topic here.